# How to add a blank column in the middle of table?

Tags: tables, pdftex

How can i add a wide column in the middle of whole table in latex? like the one shown in figure

[image: just like this table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want is not quite clear. Could you explain more, and show us what you've tried?

Comment: Your write-up and associated screenshot still isn't clear. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol,graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|C{2.5cm}|L{3cm}|} \hline
Classifier & Dimension &  \multirow{ 6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\thead{ADD THESE\\ DIMENSIONS}}}   & Total after Adding Dimensions\\ \cline{1-2} 
CDF & 4D & &\\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-4}
GO & 4D & &4D + 4D + 4D + 7D + 7D=26D\\ \cline{1-2} 
Bilateral & 4D & &  \\ \cline{1-2} 
SLDFFO & 7D & &  \\ \cline{1-2} 
SSGSM & 7D & &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]